# How to use alias from top in subquery?

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I want to use alias from top query in subquery.
Now I have error with 'artc'.

```
let query = this.articles.createQueryBuilder('artc')
      .select(['artc.title'])
      .addSelect(qb => qb
        .from(ArticlesEntity, 'artc1')
        .select('name')
        .leftJoin(AuthorsEntity, 'a', 'a.id = artc1.author_id AND artc1.id = artc.id')
      )

return await query.getRawMany();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    const query = getConnection()
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .select('title')
        .addSelect(qb => qb
            .select('name')
            .from(AuthorsEntity, 'aut')
            .leftJoin(ArticlesEntity, 'art1', 'aut.id = art1.author_id')
            .where('art1.id = art.id'),
          'name'
        )
        .from(ArticlesEntity, 'art');

    return query.getRawMany();
```